# java.lang.NullPointerException displayed when run testcase inside Groovy Script step

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to run TestCase from Groovy Script TestStep using Groovy in SoapUI.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def testCase = testRunner.testCase;
def testStep = testCase.testSteps["CreateMeeting"];
testRunner = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, null);
testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
testStep.run(testRunner, testStepContext);
```

Error displayed :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Error occured at line :

```
testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
```

Project Structure :

[image]

Comment: hard to understand the reason just by error message. better to provide full stacktrace. I guess that `testStep` is null at this point. but with stacktrace possible to identify the real problem.

Comment: Are they both on same test suite? what is your use case? why do you want to run a test case from other test case? Best thumb rule is that each test case is independent. Would you mind to show, may be with the help of screen shot, how the test case / steps are located / structured in different cases?

Comment: Yes they are in same suite. Actully i am using Groovy Script teststep to generating variable at runtime and store it to project level properties. Then at last calling the testcase. Attaching the Project structure screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Any specific reason for having that single step in a different test case? Can't you have both in steps in the same test case?

Comment: There is a For loop in 'CreateRoombooking' teststep so I want to run 'CreateMeeting' testCase each time when my values changes.

Comment: @rAJ, even then you could put both of them into same test case because there is only single test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke a Groovy test step you get a number of variables pre-declared such as `log`, `context`, and `testRunner`, so you don't have to declare your own.

This worked for me:

```
//def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def testCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("AddBooking").getTestCaseByName("CreateMeeting")
//def testStep = testCase.testSteps["CreateMeeting"]
//testRunner = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, null);
//testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap ()
testCase.run(properties, false)
```

Comment: You are running a test step. Where as the OP is trying to run a test case.

Comment: By using this i got this error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method run() on null object

Comment: The screen shot makes things clearer. Code edited above.